# Navigation to the Admin pages in a website

Tags: navigation

I am building a website in which one needs to login to get access to his /her profile
So, some of the pages are the same for the user and the admin(i.e.both of them are able to view the pages using the respective login-id)and the code I used for ensuring that no person can enter into the url and have access WITHOUT LOGGING was

```
     if (Session["cod"] == null && Session["admin"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("You need to Login.aspx");
    }
```

in the page load event
This is working absolutely fine

but the problem rises in case of those pages which are reserved for the admin;HERE THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK
here after logging even a simple user can have access by writing into the url an admin page path
Thanx in advance

Comment: I guess it would be too tedious to check for authorization in each page. Shouldn't it be done at a level up... maybe in HTTP Handler?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your AND operation in your if statement needs to be an OR.

With the logic above, a user is denied access (and redirected) if there is no `cod` session **and** no `admin` session.

This means a user with **only** a cod session will be allowed access.

Comment: When we use OR instead of AND, then the statement would become true provided whatever is the situation and the person would be redirected back to the login page

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question, then.  Can you edit your original question to add more context?

Comment: I am using a loginpage to make both the suer and the admin to login and storing there IDs in different session variables as u can view them in the code above and total navigation is based on these two variables

Answer (score 0):

In addition to redirecting to login page, you need to add some code to check authorization for each page.

For example, if a user tries to go to an admin page, you can write:

```
    if (Session["cod"] != null && Session["admin"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("user home page.aspx");
} else if (Session["cod"] == null && Session["admin"] == null) {
    Response.Redirect("You need to Login.aspx");
}
```